# Folder names with trailing spaces "appear" in Lotus Notes 8.5.3

Tags: lotus-notes

I had the following problem within the last weeks with three different Lotus Notes installations at three different companies.

Suddenly users complain, that they:

- have duplicate folders
- cannot rename certain folders
- etcetera.

When investigating the mail files, I found that folder names contained one or more trailing spaces. This looks like this:

```
Test  \  
Test  \Subfolder 1  
Test  \Subfolder 2
```

It is NOT possible to create such folders manually using the client, as trailing spaces will be deleted on save of the folder.

I am wondering, if others have these problems as well; I cannot believe that this is just a coincidence.

I could not find a known report on the IBM Knowledge Base or elsewhere online.

Comment: Domino Designer does allow the trailing spaces, but I think you have to initially go in and create the subfolder, and then go in and edit the properties to change the name. Are these folders associated with third party products? Are they folders that the users had initially created themselves? Are the users using anything other than the generic Notes client (iNotes, mobile, IMAP, 3rd party plugins) to access their mail files and manage their folders?

Comment: I know, that in Designer you can create such folders. The users having the problem definitvely don't have designer installed. Some of them are iNotes- Users, but not all. Some of them use Traveler, but again not all. There is no imap or third party software involved...